# TASM Looping characters (row & col)

Tags: loops, assembly, tasm

We have our activity in TASM to output a figure using LOOPING unfortunately no one got the correct code, so our professor make it as our homework.

> A
>
> B C
>
> D E F
>
> G H I J
>
> K L M N O

my code here is

```
@m macro row,col,char
mov ah,02
mov dl,char
int 21h

mov ah,02
mov dh,row
mov dl,col
int 10h
endm



cseg segment para 'code'
assume cs:cseg, ss:cseg, ds:cseg, es:cseg
org 100h

start: jmp begin
char1 db 'A'
col1 db 2
row1 db 0

begin: mov ax,0003
int 10h

mov cx,15

repeat: @m row1,col1,char1
        add col1,2
       add char1,1
       loop repeat
       
     int 20h
     cseg ends
     end start
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another counter (either a register or a variable) that starts out with the value 0. After printing a character, increase the counter by 1 and check if it's larger than `row1`. If it is, increase `row1` by 1, reset the counter back to 0 and reset `col1` back to 2.

(You could also do a comparison between `col1` and `row1` if you don't want to use an extra counter, but that would involve some extra arithmetic, so I chose the simplest way).

By the way, you'll probably want to change the order between `int 21h` and `int 10h` in your macro so that the first letter (`A`) is positioned correctly.